# How to set alignment in Vaadin HorizontalLayout to vertical centered?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

How can I get the Icon and the Text centered in vertical alignment inside a Vaadin HorizontalLayout?

This code isn't working:

```
HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout(VaadinIcon.EXCLAMATION_CIRCLE_O.create(),new H5("Achtung - Bitte aufmerksam lesen!") );
            horizontalLayout.setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Did you checkout the documetation? https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-ordered-layout/java-examples There are various examples

```
horizontalLayout.setJustifyContentMode(FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
```

Also checkout the webinar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efv_cPHEqdQ

Comment: Can you please post an example to reproduce your problem?